# Unity: Магазин игровых вещей

Tags: unity3d

Я хочу сделать магазин в игре, чтобы можно было покупать игровые вещи за игровые и реальные деньги. Для этого ведь нужно писать сервер? Или есть какие-то готовые решения для юнити? Немного знаком с java, как-то написал простейший сервер на спринге по туториалам, но я не хочу писать такой же сервер, так как его придется разворачивать на ВПСе, а там столько головняков что хочется повеситься. Есть ли какие-то готовые и эффективные решения, или если даже не готовые, то может простые туториалы есть?

Comment: Есть [внутриигровые покупки](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/iphone-Downloadable-Content.html)

Comment: И вообще следует добавить информацию про вашу игру это мобильная или на ПК, Какого рода покупки вам нужны...

Comment: игра под мобилки, что значит какого рода покупки? не очень понял. Расскажу подробнее: У меня две валюты: золото и кристаллы. Золото можно заработать в игре, кристаллы тоже можно заработать в игре, но и можно их купить в магазине за реальные деньги. За эти кристаллы можно будет купить что угодно в игре включая золото. Мне нужно где-то и как-то сохранять все данные игроков (прогресс, количество золота/кристаллов, экипировку и т.д.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам писать сервер не нужно, всё просто.

В зависимости от платформы на которую вы пишете игру есть магазины Apple, Google, Amazon, Samsung...
создаёте игровые деньги, к примеру коины, которых вы покупаете за реальные деньги, создаёте каталог заблокированных товаров и ещё нужно прочитать про [внутриигровые покупки](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game?playlist=17123)

Вот [ещё пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/320224/). А Сохранять данные это уже другой вопрос...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Буду изучать!

Comment: Про сохранение данных, лучше всего создать отдельный класс и работать с массивами в которые вы записываете статус вещей,  куплен или нет то есть _true_ / _false_ , не рекомендую использовать json файлы если вы не умеете их как то криптовать так как вашу игру смогут взломать.

Comment: есть ли по поводу этого какой-нибудь простой туториал?

Comment: К сожалению нет, но можешь найти проект  какой нибуть и проанализировать код, может сразу не поимёшь, зато пример будет